# Android: how to make a method of getting something from a service with onActivityResult()?

Tags: java, android, service

I'm trying to make a method that can return a result from service
Problem is this :

```
public int getResult{
    int result;
    //I'm sending request with PendingIntent here, but here I don't have my variable returned
    return result;
}
public void onActivityResult (int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    //because a result from a service comes here and i can't put it in a previous method - that's a problem for me 
}
```

Is there any idea of making int getResult method that will not only send request but will return a result as well?

Comment: Have You tried to bind a Service? It might let You get result sync way, but it will also block getResult() thread execution.

Comment: What you're trying to do would block the UIThread so you shouldn't

Comment: Possible duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17460013/the-best-way-to-deliver-result-from-service-binding-in-android/17460364#

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can implement a listener in your activity, that the service calls when it gets the job done. And in that listener, you can fetch the result from the service..

It is best way I believe.

Comment: ok..how exactly should be it done?I'm new to all this programming
i have a method - getResult()- what should I do in it? My need is to set MediaPlayer service where I can start player from one activity and stop from another for example. but doing something like getDuration() doesnt return result anyhow

Answer (score 0):

Ok, you mean you want to start the service from one activity (say, activityA) and stop it from another (say, activityB)... For that follow the given steps:

1. Start your service from activityA (This will let your service run even after the activity gets destroyed).
2. In onResume() of activityA bind your service to this activityA (this will return you a binder which you can use to control the service).
3. In onPause() of activityA unBind the service from this activityA (your service will still keep on running since at first you have started it).
4. Start your activityB at any point of time from activityA and in onResume() of activityB again bind your service to this activityB (this will return you a binder to the same running service since services are singleton, and you can use this binder to control, i.e. to stop, in your case, the service).
5. And, in onResume() of activityB again unBind your service from this activityB...

I guess, I've made all the points clear... Happy programming.. ;-)